# SQL Server different time duration between stmtcompleted and direct query

Tags: sql-server, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have then following tracert about one query in my application:

[image]

As you can see, the query reads all registers in the table and the result is a big impact in time duration.

But when I try to execute the query directly the result is another... What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: are you executing query in the 2nd example or just checking the explain plan?

Comment: It is likely blocked by other processes using INVENTSUM. Add BlockedProcessReport to the trace and configure the Blocked Process Threshold to 1 second, temporarily, then put it back to the original value when you have finished investigating.

Comment: Try turning on statistics in your query in SSMS and see how the number of reads and CPU time compares to your trace.

Comment: You can try run this first in you query window: SET STATISTICS TIME ON. After this and run query you will see the elapsed time in Messages tab.

Answer (score 4):

You executed ANOTHER query from SSMS.

The query shown in profiler is part of stored procedure, and has 8 parameters.
What you've executed is a query with constants that has another execution plan as all the constants are known and estimation was done in base of these known values.

When your sp's statement was executed the plan was created for god-knows-what sniffed parameters and this plan is different from what you have in SSMS.

From the thikness of arrows in SSMS it's clear that you query does not do 7.954.449 reads.

If you want to see you actual execution plan in profiler you should select corresponding event (Showplan XML Statistics Profile ).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are two different queries. The Axapta uses placeholders in common. Your query uses literal constants.

The `forceLiterals` hint in the query make the Axapta query similar to your SSMS sample. Default Axapta hint is `forcePlaceholders`.

Main goal of placeholders is optimize a massive stream of similar queries with different constants from multiple clients. Mainly due to the use of a query plans cache.

---

see also the injection warning for forceLiterals:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa861766.aspx